# unable to call a function from jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with the following code ?
Am I missing some basics here ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        function myfun() {
            $('#inputtext').val('hello world');
        } ;
        $('#fillbutton').click(function(){ myfun();});
    </script>
        <input type="text" id="inputtext" name="inputtext" value="" />
        <input type="button" id="fillbutton" value="Fill with Text"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am expecting the following behaviour from the code. 
User clicks on the "Fill with text" button. then the myfun() will put the hello world inside the text field area. 
This is not working although I can call the myfun() from the Google chrome javascript console and see the expected result. Please help me out.

Answer (score 6):

you must put the listener after document ready, see this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fillbutton').click(function(){ myfun();});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your jQuery event is not working, because you bind this event before you dom is ready.
Put your script into `$(document).ready(function(){})`

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        function myfun() {
            $('#inputtext').val('hello world');
        } ;
        $('#fillbutton').click(function(){ myfun();});
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are binding the event when the HTML is not present there

The below line bind the event

```
`   $('#fillbutton').click(function(){ myfun();});`
```

Alternative

a) Place the code at the bottom before closing `</body>` tag

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <script>
                function myfun() {
                    $('#inputtext').val('hello world');
                } ;
                $('#fillbutton').click(function(){ myfun();});
            </script>
                <input type="text" id="inputtext" name="inputtext" value="" />
                <input type="button" id="fillbutton" value="Fill with Text"/>
            <script>
                $('#fillbutton').click(function(){ myfun();});
            </script>               
            </body>
        </html>
```

b) Or user jquery `ready` function

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <script>
                function myfun() {
                    $('#inputtext').val('hello world');
                } ;

                $(document).read(function(){
                   $('#fillbutton').click(function(){ myfun();});
                })
            </script>
                <input type="text" id="inputtext" name="inputtext" value="" />
                <input type="button" id="fillbutton" value="Fill with Text"/>           
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your code in `ready` event:
This will wait for the page to load completely and run the function. Because you are adding events on elements which are not loaded on page the event are not binded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fillbutton').on('click', myfun);
});
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Add "onclick" attribute like below for your input element. It will work.

```html
 <input type="button" id="fillbutton" onclick="return myfun();" value="Fill with Text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your js code `$(function(){ })`

```
$(function(){
    function myfun() {
        $('#inputtext').val('hello world');
    };
    $('#fillbutton').click(function() {
        myfun();
    });
})
```